# SQL Server trigger (before insert) to validate data?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

We have an application that we use in the warehouse to track which pickers are picking which orders.  We have an instance every so often where the the order number that is inserted into the table is not the actual order number. While we are going to put in some validation on the application, I was wondering how we could put a trigger in place on the Table to prevent writing the record when the order number is wrong.

For example:

- Before insert, when len(ordernum) <> '6' then delete record.
- else insert into Table1

?

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have any `BEFORE INSERT` triggers. You can either use an `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger - or then rethink your logic to see if you can handle it with an `AFTER INSERT` trigger

Comment: @marc_s Can't you cancel the transaction from the AFTER INSERT trigger, making it effectively a BEFORE INSERT ?

Comment: @nicomp: well, yes, that's the only "way out" - if you detect something in the `AFTER INSERT` trigger that isn't valid, you can cancel the transaction that's running (that actually fired the trigger)

Comment: @marc_s I think it's a great way out because you have the surrogate keys at that point but you are still isolated from the rest of the database.

Comment: A ** check** constraint would easily prevent this - and would be trivial to create. In addition, is this a case where there is a lack of referential integrity? Seems like such a column should be a foreign key to an order table.

Comment: @SMor Well that was easy!  Thanks!  Not sure how to flag your comment as the answer, but upvoted it for you.

Comment: If @SMor posts it as an answer, then you can accept it as one. I'm afraid that's not how comments work though.

Answer (score 0):

INSTEAD OF triggers cause their source DML operation to skip and they just execute the code provided inside them. Actual insert, delete or update operation do not occur at all. However they have their associated inserted and deleted tables simulating the DML operation. Inserted and deleted tables are widely used in operations inside triggers

```
    --Instead of Trigger
    CREATE TRIGGER BeforeDelete_Trigger ON [dbo].[Order1]
    INSTEAD OF INSERT AS
    BEGIN
     IF (SELECT * FROM Order1 WHERE len(ordernum) <> '6')
     THEN 
    INSERT INTO Order1;
   ELSE
    INSERT INTO Order2 (col 1, col 2) VALUES (inserted.col1, inserted.col2);
     END;
     GO
```

Answer (score -1):

you can create an instead of trigger:

--Create an INSTEAD OF INSERT trigger on the table:

```
CREATE TRIGGER InsteadTrigger on dbo.table1
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  if  len(inserted.ordernum)= 6
     insert into table1 (ordernum,col1, col2) values (inserted.ordernum,inserted.col1, inserted.col2)
--rows that dont have a ordernum length of 6 are not inserted

end
```

Comment: MSMS is acting like it does not understand "inserted" as an identifier.

Comment: @MattC It's not acting, the syntax is incorrect. You can't reference `inserted` without a `FROM` clause. Also, the answerer has logic that is treating the insert like it would only contain 1 row. I wouldn't follow the guidance of this one as it stands.